# Marking a variadic closure parameter as escaping

Tags: swift, closures

Assuming a `@nonescaping` variadic closure parameter as in

```
func method(_ closures: () -> Void...)
```

then mutating it to `@escaping` as in

```
func method(_ closures: @escaping () -> Void...)
```

produces the following error.

> @escaping attribute may only be used in function parameter position

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29750368/7880059 may be the answer.

Comment: `func method(_ closures: [@escaping () -> Void])` produces the same error as of Swift 4.

Comment: It’s a compiletime error. As far as I can see `@escaping` and `@autoclosure` are exclusively supported by the function type.   

_Edit: I was replying to Özgür Ersil’s now deleted comment._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `@escaping` here at all. Only a closure that is directly an argument (with nothing wrapping it) can be non-escaping.

A closure that is part of a variadic argument is (under the hood) wrapped in an `Array`, so it is already implicitly `@escaping`.

For example, this compiles and runs just fine:

```
class MyObject {

    var closures: [() -> ()] = []

    func add(_ closures: () -> () ...) {
        self.closures += closures
    }

    func run() {
        for closure in closures { closure() }
    }

}

let object = MyObject()
object.add({ print("first") }, { print("second") })
object.run()
```